# Change a JButton back to the original "metal" color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, background-color

I'm writing a program where when a button is clicked, it turns blue. I've accomplished this using:

```
button.setBackground(Color.BLUE)
```

However, when it is clicked a second time, I want to change it back to the original "metal" look. I've Googled and Googled and cannot  figure out how to do this anywhere. How do you change a JButton back to the original "metal" color?

Answer (score 6):

Try [`Component#setBackground(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29). This way, the component will inherit the background color of its parent.